# Can't select a group of element in Foundation, be replaced by default

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

I'm using a combination of elements provided by Foundation 5. Now I can't select the elements and change their css property because my CSS selector doesn't work, can anyone help me to focus on them correctly?
They are a group of button with "reveal modal" effect.

```
<a href="#" data-reveal-id="align" data-reveal class="button [radius round]">Alignment</a>
<a href="#" data-reveal-id="size" data-reveal class="button [radius round]">Font-Size</a>
<a href="#" data-reveal-id="decoration" data-reveal class="button [radius round]">Decoration</a>
<a href="#" data-reveal-id="transform" data-reveal class="button [radius round]">Transform</a>
<a href="#" data-reveal-id="spacing"  data-reveal class="button [radius round]">Spacing</a>
<a href="#" data-reveal-id="shadow" data-reveal class="button [radius round]">Shadow</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the problem. I didn't wrap all the element in a group; the title was used to select the following elements, but the title is the only one outside of the group, so the title'id has none descendant. That's the problem, not Foundation 5.